# How to implement security in Power BI embedded code?

Tags: powerbi

I have one Power BI file that needs to be embedded in the Power App Portal using Power BI embedded code (iFrame code). I am filtering the iFrame code by applying query parameter filter in the Embedded URL. 
The issue is that the value of query parameter can be changed by any end-user who is aware of the value.

For example, if we are passing user id in query string, another user id who knows the values can also change the user id in the same query string.

My question is how to securly pass the parameter in the P-BI embedded? Is there any special encryption method so that the parameter value is encrypted at end user to avoid changing the user ID

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement RLS (Row Level Security). That way, users logging in to view the iFrame will see only data he is supposed to view. You will have to configure roles in power bi-level to determine how data access is determined for each user.

Read [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-admin-rls) to find out more about RLS.

Comment: Thanks but we have set of users who are using PowerApp to login and they wanted to integrate Power BI inside PowerApp. Once they login into the portal, they wanted to see Power BI dashboard related to the Login ID that they have used to login into PowerApp

Comment: @xorpower RLS is the way to go, but you can use `userprincipalname()` DAX function to get the name of the logged in user and filter the data based on that, so no parameters need to be passed at all.